# Using a $lookup with $group in Mongo/Mongoose Aggtregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

We have set up some wrapper request functions to normalize how we're handling requests. One of the functions we've set up is an aggregate function. It looks like this:

```
  async aggregate(mongooseModelObject, aggregateObject = {}) {
    try {
      return await mongooseModelObject.aggregate(aggregateObject).exec();
    } catch (err) {
      this.sendError(err);
    }
  }
```

This works fine when I use it like this:

```
exports.getCountByBranch = async function (req, res) {
  let docs;
  let request = new EndpointRequestController(req, res);

  try {
    docs = await request.aggregate(staffmember, [{
      $group: {
        _id: "$branch",
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }]);
  } catch (err) {
    return request.sendError("An error occurred while trying to find existing records.", err);
  }
  request.documentCount = docs.length;
  request.sendResponse(docs);
}
```

But what I'd like to do, to make this more user-friendly for the end-user, is run a `populate` to include the branch "name", rather than just the "_id". So I would assume that's as simple as adding another stage using a `$lookup`. That's what I would do if I was just calling the mongoose function directly. So that said, I tried this:

```
exports.getCountByBranch = async function (req, res) {
  let docs;
  let request = new EndpointRequestController(req, res);

  try {
    docs = await request.aggregate(staffmember, [{
      $lookup: {
        from: "branches",
        localField: "branch",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "branch"
      },
      $group: {
        _id: "$branch",
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }]);
  } catch (err) {
    return request.sendError("An error occurred while trying to find existing records.", err);
  }
  request.documentCount = docs.length;
  request.sendResponse(docs);
}
```

But this errors out with this:

> Error: Arguments must be aggregate pipeline operators

What am I missing here?

Comment: try `.allowDiskUse(true)`

Comment: use this [{
      $lookup: {
        from: "branches",
        localField: "branch",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "branch"
      }},
      {$group: {
        _id: "$branch",
        count: {
          $sum: 1
        }
      }
    }]
curly braces not closed properly in pipeline stages

Comment: That was it, thanks @SenthurDeva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it's working fine

```
exports.getCountByBranch = async function (req, res) {
let docs;
let request = new EndpointRequestController(req, res);

try {
    docs = await request.aggregate(staffmember, [{
        $lookup: {
            from: "branches",
            localField: "branch",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "branch"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$branch",
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            }
        }
    }]);
} catch (err) {
    return request.sendError("An error occurred while trying to find existing records.", err);
}
request.documentCount = docs.length;
request.sendResponse(docs);
```

}